# install4j downloadable components initially included in installer

Tags: install4j

We are writing an installer where few custom programs are written to update selective components.
Requirement is to keep few components downloadable which could be updated later by custom programs. Along with that an initial version of components should be delivered with installer file.
If we pack components with installer then dat files are not available to download neither updater knows the update URL.
Any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You mark single components as downloadable on the

Files->Installation Components->Options

tab.

In the media wizard, on the "Data files" step, you have to choose the "Downloadable" option and provide the download URL.

A custom installer application can install a downloadable component with a "Download and install component" action.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.
This is how we are doing it right now.
Challenge we are facing is that we need to pack downloadable component in initial installer, which is not happening right now.

Comment: You can define another media file with a different setting on the "Data files" step of the media wizard.

Comment: Yes tried that as well, but ultimately we will distribute only 1 file initially. And then send updates onwards through downloadable components.

Comment: Adding to that a media file containing downloadable components dont look for updates..as no url is provided...and a media file with download option doesnt contain components initially..

Comment: "distribute only 1 file initially. And then send updates onwards through downloadable components."  --> I don't see how that could work with install4j

Comment: Please consider this feature, in slow internet conditions its hard to deliver >50 MB updates.